# CoreData: Does executing a fetch request with predicate always cause I/O read?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Core Data: does a fetch have to make a trip to persistent store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13833529/core-data-does-a-fetch-have-to-make-a-trip-to-persistent-store)

Say I have a array containing all objects of a entity that i fetched before, which will be faster to get objects with special condition, for example, `attributeX = @"attribute value"`?

1. use `NSFetchRequest` with predicate and execute it.
2. filter the array by objc fast enumeration.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing option 3, which is using a predicate to filter the array. That would remove the round trip to the database. [It's detailed here in Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html).

The [`filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BAJJDBEB) method on `NSArray` is the one to use.

Comment: thanks, option 3 is the same theory with option 2 I think, I just want to make sure If when never I perform a fetch, it will incur a trip to persistent store.