# Core Data: does a fetch have to make a trip to persistent store?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

Say I do this:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = #a managed object context";
NSString *entityName = #an entity name#;
NSFetchRequest *requestForAll = [NSFetchRequest requestWithEntityName:entityName];
NSArray *allObj = [context executeFetchRequest:requestForAll];

for (NSString *name in allNamesArray){
    NSFetchRequest *requestForOne = [NSFetchRequest requestWithEntityName:entityName];
    requestForOne.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@",name];
    NSArray *ObjsWithName = [context executeFetchRequest:requestForOne];
    #do some work with the obj#
}
```

Does the fetch in the loop incur a trip to the persistent store every time? Or those fetches will only be performed in coredata's row cache?

**EDIT**
I've written a fragment of testing code :
You need to create a core data entity named "Person" and it should have an attribute named "name", which is of type string.

use this code to populate some data:

```
self.array = @[@"alkjsdfkllaksjdf",@"asldjflkajdklsfjlk;aj",@"aflakjsdl;kfjalksdjfklajkldhkl;aj",@"aljdfkljalksdjfl;j" ,@"flajdl;kfjaklsdjflk;j",@"akldsjfklajdslkf",@"alkdjfkljaklsdjflkaj",@"alsdjflkajsdflj",@"adlkfjlkajsdfkljkla",@"alkdjfklajslkdfj"];

NSString *firstRunKey = @"oh its first run!";
NSString *firstRun = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:firstRunKey];
if (!firstRun) {
    for (NSString *name in self.array) {
        Person *p = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        p.name = name;
    }
}
[self.managedObjectContext save];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:firstRunKey forKey:firstRunKey];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

profile this two methods and you'll find usingCoreData costs much more time than usingFilterArray!

```
static int caseCount = 1000;
-(void)usingCoreData
{
    NSLog(@"core data");
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Person"];
    NSArray *allPersons = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];

    for (int i = 0; i < caseCount; i++){
        for (NSString *name in self.array) {
            request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@",name];
            NSArray *result = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
        }
    }
}

-(void)usingFilterArray
{
    NSLog(@"filter array");
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Person"];
    NSArray *allPersons = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];

    for (int i = 0; i < caseCount; i++){
        for (NSString *name in self.array) {
            NSArray *array = [allPersons filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@",name]];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess I need to answer my question myself.

I tested it and found, every time a fetch executed, core data will translate your NSFetchRequest into SQL command and invoke a data base query,the query result is firstly NSManagedObjectIDs, caching is applied to get the NSManagedObject from a NSManagedObjectID.

In conclusion, it caches object, but doesn't cache query result.

That means you execute the same NSFetchRequest for 10 times, it will query your persistent store for 10 times, event though you will get 10 times the same result. So in such situation, filtering array in memory will perform better than fetching.

Answer (score 0):

The fetch will come from the specified cache when available.

EDIT:
Here's a link to a great tutorial that shows how to set up a `NSFetchedResultsController` that uses a cache.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/?p=999

Comment: The document called common sense...otherwise what is the cache for?  Well you can confirm it if you wish.  The article mentions a way to turn on all SQL commands to see what is really happening.

Comment: @borrrden that's not very nice

Comment: Nope, it's not...but to me asking for "a document telling this" is like saying "I don't believe your answer"

Comment: @borrrden It sounds like he's looking for a proof, you know, that's how computer science works, and science in general, proof based. But I think you already know that...

Comment: @borrrden I use to consider that core data will filter in the cache instead of a make a trip to persistent store too. But I found using fetch with predicate is much more slower than filtering array using the same predicate in memory(I didn't insert/update/remove any new row in core data while benchmarking), that's why I'm asking here. Also why I don't use NSFetchedResultController is that it is async, I can't use is in my current problem.

Comment: The first trip will, of course, be a fault and cause a round trip.  But after that it will keep the data in memory *as much as it can*

Comment: @borrrden I've added a test case, if it doesn't bother you, please try it with time profiler and you'll see fetching uses much more time than filtering array, it looks like every fetch have to go into persistent store.

Comment: It doesn't...a quick search of the documentation says it outright, but of course you are recreating a large array every time...that's why it is slower.  Quoting the docs -> "If you fetch some objects, work with them, and then execute a new fetch that includes a superset of those objects, you do not get new instances or update data for the existing objects—you get the existing objects with their current in-memory state."

Comment: @borrrden No,it's not creating array, two methods creates same number of array with same number of elements.

Comment: executeFetchRequest will make an array of the objects inside the managed object context.  So the first example creates an array 10,000 times, while the second one only creates it once and uses it 10,000 times.